# Apache request time - what's wrong?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, performance, xdebug

I make JSON API and when measuring performance there's this strange thing. When doing XDEBUG_PROFILE, request processing takes about 100 ms. But browser network panel says it's always 1 - 1.5 seconds. Why so big difference and how do I know what causes it?

System is GNU/Linux, Apache 2.2.17

Comment: Perhaps latency?

Comment: @tjameson Requesting small static files from same server takes about 150 ms.

Answer (score 1):

Profiling code will give you the time to compile/run code.

Browser network metrics, will give you the DNS + TCP + HTTP ( + profiled code) steps time.

Comment: If i'm doing CURL from the same server (console) I see the response time is ~1.5 seconds after request. So it's not latency and not a network issue.